# Is there a difference between red painted glass and painted red glass?

Tags: difference, attributives

Is there a difference between red painted glass and painted red glass? I guess painted red glass can be yellow, green, or etc..

Comment: Is "painted glass" common?  I see "stained glass" and "coloured glass", but do many people paint glass?

Comment: @JamesK It's fairly common for Pyrex cookware to be painted glass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Yes, there is a difference.

As a native English speaker, the way I would naturally interpret these two statements is as follows:

A "painted red glass" is a glass made from red material, which has then been painted (with paint of any color).

A "red painted glass" is a glass made from material of any color, which has then been painted with red paint.